# Ubuntu 20.04.4 Wifi Channel 2.4GHz Poor Signal

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have an HP Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.4, kernel version: 5.15.0-46-generic
. Normally I use the 5G channel of my router in my home, and it's working fine. But when I use 2.4G, it could not connect or get a poor signal, though it performs well on other devices. I have to use only 2.4G in my office, so I have no other option.

`wlist chan`

```
  no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 144 : 5.72 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Current Frequency=5.765 GHz
```

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 10:62:e5:c9:3e:94
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-46-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4104000-a4104fff memory:a4100000-a4103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 74:40:bb:31:83:ab
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.15.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4000000-a400ffff
```

```
nmcli device wifi list
```

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  Dip-Home 5G       Infra  153   135 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
*       XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  Dip-Home          Infra  9     270 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

Here, 'Dip-Home' is the 2.4G Connection, and 'Dip-Home 5G' is the 5G Connection of the same router. 'Dip-Home 5G' is working fine, And the system trying to connect it every time by default priority. So I forgot the connection of 'Dip-Home 5G' from the wifi settings so that it can't prioritize it. And try to connect 'Dip Home' which is 2.4G. This connection is sluggish, though I was just in front of the router. The same things happened everywhere.

Can anyone suggest something to solve it?

Comment: How poor? While sitting in your office, please run: `nmcli device wifi list` Next, edit your question to include your 2.4 gHz network only and redact the MAC address with xxxx.

Comment: Sir, I updated the information according to your instruction, My 2.4G connection is problematic everywhere. So I could test it on my home router.

Comment: Are you using the default driver or have you installed `rtl88212ce-dkms`? Years ago it only worked with the latter but now it works out-of-the-box but with an unstable driver.

Answer (score 0):

Install `rtl8821ce-dkms` either at Additional Drivers or run:

`sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`

and reboot.